# How do I prepopulate textarea with data from database (or any text for that matter) in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an form which edits data in my database. I have the following inputs:

```
<input value="@title" type="text" asp-for="@Model.ProjName" class="form-control" placeholder="Ticket1" />
<textarea  value="@description" type="text" asp-for="@Model.ProjDescription" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
```

I can pre-populate the input just fine, however **value** doesn't work on the textarea. What is the correct way of populating it?

Comment: `<textarea>@description</textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem. Text area acts differently from input tag . So instead of using value parameter, add your value between open and close tag of text area

```
 <textarea  type="text" asp-for="@Model.ProjDescription" class="form-control" rows="3">@Model.description</textarea>
```

Here is a .net fiddle with an example
https://dotnetfiddle.net/2TYEOk

Comment: This doesnt work for me. To give you more details, the form is inside a modal pop-up and @description =@Model.ProjectList.Where(p => p.Id ==Model.ID).FirstOrDefault().ProjectDescription.ToString();

Comment: Please edit your post and add the following: 1. Controller code , 2. Full Razor code, 3. jQuery or Javascript code if available.

Answer (score -1):

Since you use `asp-for="@Model.ProjDescription"`,so the default value will be `@Model.ProjDescription`,if you want to bind value with `@description`,you can try to use id and name to replace `asp-for="@Model.ProjDescription"`.Here is the sample code:

```
<textarea type="text" id="ProjDescription" name="ProjDescription" class="form-control" rows="3" >@description</textarea>
```